# rotating sprite on touch libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to rotate my sprite when i push to go left. right now my character is idling and running to the right. but im having trouble rotating to the left.

here is my chunk of code. if anyone could help me, that would be awesome.

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    //continue to keep looping




    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        int xTouch = Gdx.input.getX();
        int yTouch = Gdx.input.getY();
        //System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4);
        //go left
        if(xTouch < (width/4) && yTouch > height - (height/6)){
            currentRunFrame = runAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
            spriteBatch.draw(currentRunFrame,  runSprite.getX() - 32, runSprite.getY() + 150, 128, 128);
            RealGame.leftButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("leftButtonOver.png"));
            moveLeft();
        }
        if(xTouch > (width/4) && xTouch < (width/4)*2 && yTouch > height - (height/6)){
            currentRunFrame = runAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
            spriteBatch.draw(currentRunFrame,  runSprite.getX() - 32, runSprite.getY() + 150, 128, 128);
            RealGame.rightButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("rightButtonOver.png"));
            moveRight();
        }
        if(xTouch > (width/4) * 2 && xTouch < (width/4) * 3 && yTouch > height - (height/6)){
            RealGame.shootButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("shootButtonOver.png"));
        }
        if(xTouch > (width/4) * 3 && xTouch < (width/4) * 4 && yTouch > height - (height/6)){
            RealGame.jumpButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("jumpButtonOver.png"));
        }

    }
    if(!Gdx.input.isTouched()){

        currentIdleFrame = idleAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        spriteBatch.draw(currentIdleFrame,  idleSprite.getX() - 32, idleSprite.getY() + 150, 128, 128);
        RealGame.leftButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("leftButton.png"));
        RealGame.rightButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("rightButton.png"));
        RealGame.shootButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("shootButton.png"));
        RealGame.jumpButton = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("jumpButton.png"));
        moveStop();

    }

}
```

thank you in advance, and let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `currentIdleFrame` is a `Texture` or `TextureRegion`, not a `Sprite`. One of `SpriteBatch`s draw methode with `Texture` supports a `flipX` and `flipY`. Using this you can flip him, for example if you are walking to the left, but your `Texture` is facing to the right. Also this supports `rotation`, which should be the rotation in degrees.

Verry important note: You create `new Texture` every render loop. Don't do this. Instead load all your `Texture`s in a `Texture[] frames` and draw the right one, depending on `stateTime`. Also take a look at `Animations` class, which will help you with this.

Hope i could help

Comment: thank you for that tip about creating new buttons on that loop. i was trying to figure out why my app was dying after 26 seconds. well... now i know why

Comment: Try to create objects in `create()`, `show()` or `constructor`, as they are called only once, when they are actually needed. Creating `new objects` in render can be a bit heavy, so only use it if absolutly neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SpriteBatch draw method that takes boolean flipX parameter or call flip on the Sprite.

Oh, and if this is your main loop, stop loading the textures like you are. Load them in the beginning and just swap them as needed.